# Is there a way to display only changes and errors

Tags: salt-stack

I have quite extensive salt config and I want to be able to see what has changed. If I just run `salt '*' state.highstate` I got the whole list with things that were present and not changed - like 3 to 4 screens of log. But I'd really like to see only things that changed in the last job.

It doesn't have to work for the salt call, it can also employ `salt-run jobs.lookup_jid`.

Comment: the fine manual has current info.
https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/output/all/salt.output.highstate.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can set `state_verbose: False` in `/etc/salt/master` or `/etc/salt/minion`.
If you want to shorten the output to one line per state, set `state_output: terse`.

You can also pass these filters on command line:

```
salt --state-output=terse '*' state.highstate
```

If you only want to see changes, you can use `state-output=changes` or `state-output=mixed`. The latter one will show more information on a failure.

See the following answers fore more detail: [basepi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17055524/1986344), [psarossy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28298811/1986344)

Comment: Is there a way to specify this on the command line, example: salt '*' state.highstate state_output=terse

Comment: salt --state-output=terse '*' state.highstate

Comment: is this kind of filtering available on salt-call as well? doesn't seem to be.

Comment: The `--state-output` flag is also available for the salt-call command.

Answer (score 38):

We've also added `state_output: mixed` which will give you the same output as `terse`, except if there's a failure, in which case it will give you the more verbose output.

Comment: what's the difference between state_output: mixed and state_output: changes?

Comment: Pretty sure `changes` will show only things that changed or fail. But I can't remember off the top of my head.

Answer (score 24):

To actually answer the question, yes, there is an output filter for changes only:

```
salt '*' state.highstate --state-output=changes
```

This will display one liners for things that are in the right state and the proper output for the changes. ie:

```
  <...>
  Name: /etc/sudoers - Function: file.managed - Result: Clean
  Name: /etc/timezone - Function: file.managed - Result: Clean
  Name: /etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt - Function: file.managed - Result: Clean
  Name: /etc/init.d/logstash-forwarder - Function: file.managed - Result: Clean
----------
          ID: /etc/logstash-forwarder
    Function: file.managed
      Result: True
     Comment: File /etc/logstash-forwarder updated
     Started: 14:14:28.580950
    Duration: 65.664 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              diff:
                  ---
                  +++
                  @@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
                   {
                     "network": {
                  -    "servers": [ "10.0.0.104:5000" ],
                  +    "servers": [ "10.0.0.72:5000" ],
                       "timeout": 15,
                       "ssl ca": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
                     },

  Name: deb http://packages.elasticsearch.org/logstashforwarder/debian stable main - Function: pkgrepo.managed - Result: Clean
  Name: logstash-forwarder - Function: pkg.installed - Result: Clean
  <...>
```

Comment: what's the difference between state_output=mixed and state_output=changes?

Comment: @eMBee `mixed` output has a terse output for changes. You should see a single line for all results. `changes` shows the full diff for a change at the end of the run. You probably want `changes`.

Comment: @eMBee - you should ask this as a new question.  It's documented in `/etc/salt/master` on your salt-master host.

Answer (score 14):

There are 2 options, first is to change the state_output in master's configuration file, like mentioned in the accepted answer, and it also possible to override the state output in command line, like:

```
salt --state-output=mixed \* test.version
```

Answer (score 5):

As of the following PR that was merged into Salt 2015.8.0 (https://github.com/saltstack/salt/pull/26962) it is now possible to toggle the `state_verbose` flag from command line when running highstate. This overrides the config you can set in `/etc/salt/master` that was mentioned in previous answers.

The following command should now display only the changes and errors from a highstate run `salt '*' state.highstate --state-verbose=False`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below to shorten the output in one line and then filter that output to show only the changes:

salt -v 'minion' state.highstate test=True --state-output=terse --state-verbose=False

Comment: Please help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation. Also, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help